# How do I validate a field based on it's initial value in forms.py?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a custom self.clean method in forms.py which contains a check on whether the POSTed date values overlap with existing records. In the case where the user edits their record, but does not change the dates, this validation stops the record update. How can I change the validation with If statement or otherwise dependant on if the user has modified the start_date or end_date fields?

I've tried looking at things like self.get_initial() and self.has_changed() which seem to only be applicable in the view function? I'd rather validate in forms.py.

If I could filter out the record currently being edited from my "overlap" validations, that may be the neatest solution.

forms.py:

```
class EditBookingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bookings
        #user not included as that is handled in views
        fields = ['start_date', 'end_date', 'type', 'approved', 'members', 'guests']
...
    def clean(self):
        form_data = self.cleaned_data    

        #check if dates overlap by more than one day (ie. can start/end on the same day)
        overlap_in = Bookings.objects.filter(start_date__lt=form_data['start_date'], end_date__gt=form_data['end_date']).count()
        overlap_st = Bookings.objects.filter(start_date__lt=form_data['start_date'], end_date__gt=form_data['start_date']).count()
        overlap_end = Bookings.objects.filter(start_date__lt=form_data['end_date'], end_date__gt=form_data['end_date']).count()
        overlap_same = Bookings.objects.filter(start_date=form_data['start_date'], end_date=form_data['end_date']).count()       
        overlap_over = Bookings.objects.filter(end_date__gt=form_data['start_date'], start_date__lt=form_data['end_date']).count()

        overlap = overlap_end + overlap_in + overlap_same + overlap_st + overlap_over

        if overlap > 0:
            self._errors["start_date"] = ["Your dates overlap with an existing booking"]
            del form_data["start_date"]
            return form_data
```

views.py:

```
    booking = get_object_or_404(Bookings, pk=booking_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditBookingForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            #some code

    #if not POST request  
    else:
        form = EditBookingForm(instance=booking)

context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'bookings/edit_booking_page.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ModelForm that is editing an existing instance will be passed the instance that is being edited when initialized. You should be able to use this pre-edit instance and exclude it's pk from your querysets

```
bookings = Bookings.objects.all()

if self.instance.pk:
    bookings = bookings.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)

overlap_in = bookings.filter(start_date__lt=form_data['start_date'], end_date__gt=form_data['end_date']).count()
# etc
```

Your 5 querysets can by simplified to at most 3 so long as you validate that end_date is greater than start_date. It's probably possible to reduce them to 1...

```
    # So long as end_date is greater than start_date then this should be covered by overlap_st
    # overlap_in = Bookings.objects.filter(start_date__lt=form_data['start_date'], end_date__gt=form_data['end_date']).count()
    overlap_st = Bookings.objects.filter(start_date__lt=form_data['start_date'], end_date__gt=form_data['start_date']).count()
    # So long as end_date is greater than start_date then this should be covered by overlap_over 
    # overlap_end = Bookings.objects.filter(start_date__lt=form_data['end_date'], end_date__gt=form_data['end_date']).count()
    overlap_same = Bookings.objects.filter(start_date=form_data['start_date'], end_date=form_data['end_date']).count()       
    overlap_over = Bookings.objects.filter(end_date__gt=form_data['start_date'], start_date__lt=form_data['end_date']).count()
```

Comment: When trying that I get self.instanace.pk = None. Am I doing something wrong in the view when passing the instance?:`def edit_booking_view(request, booking_id):

    booking = get_object_or_404(Bookings, pk=booking_id)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditBookingForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            #some code
        
    #if not POST 
    else:
        form = EditBookingForm(instance=booking)`

Comment: Can you share your view?

Comment: You should pass the instance even when the method is "POST". `EditBookingForm(request.POST, instance=booking)`

Comment: Made a quick suggestion regarding the number of queryeets